# Проблема с SQL. Timestamp и update

Tags: sql

Имеется sql-запрос к таблице mysql вот такой:

```
" UPDATE `data` SET `special` = 'NotThisYear' WHERE `special` = 'ThisYear' "
```

, он работает, но есть проблема в том что при update мне не нужно обновлять дату выбранных записей, которая записывалась при INSERT'е данных записей в таблицу. 
Что если последовательно записывать в массив значение дат и потом их тем же апдейтом ставить?
Это логично,
но не думаю что нету других путей. Дата имеет вид TIMESTAMP

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса DDL таблицы. Вероятно, для поля с датой указано `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Если так, и при любом изменении требуется не трогать это поле - проще и правильнее удалить `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, обновляя его явно в запросе в тех редких случаях, когда это необходимо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE data SET special = 'NotThisYear', date_time = date_dime WHERE special = 'ThisYear'
```

`date_time = date_dime` - не знаю как у вас называется колонка, этот код (название колонки) для примера привёл просто.